# Pandas difference in index with date values

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a DataFrame like this

```
Date           value
04 May 2015     1
06 May 2015     1
07 May 2015     1
11 May 2015     1
11 May 2015     1
```

How do I get the diff of the Date Index? i.e. the third col below:

```
Date           value   Diff
04 May 2015     1      NA
06 May 2015     1       2
07 May 2015     1       1
11 May 2015     1       4
11 May 2015     1       0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate time difference between Pandas Dataframe indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices)

Answer (score 19):

you can use [pandas.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

```
>>> df['Diff'] = df.index.to_series().diff()

            value     Diff
Date                    
2015-05-04      1      NaT
2015-05-06      1   2 days
2015-05-07      1   1 days
2015-05-11      1   4 days
2015-05-11      1   0 days
```

elegant way to convert to float is

```
df['Diff'] = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.days
>>df
            value  Diff
Date                   
2015-05-04      1   NaN
2015-05-06      1   2.0
2015-05-07      1   1.0
2015-05-11      1   4.0
2015-05-11      1   0.0
```

more faster way is to typecast to days

```
df.index.to_series().diff().astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

to convert to Integer (pandas verson >= [0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support))

```
df.index.to_series().diff().astype('timedelta64[D]').astype('Int64') 
>>df
            value  Diff
Date                   
2015-05-04      1   NaN
2015-05-06      1     2
2015-05-07      1     1
2015-05-11      1     4
2015-05-11      1     0
```

Note : Int64 is [Pandas Nullable Integer](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/integer_na.html) Data Type (not int64)

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like:

```
df["Diff"] = df.index
df["Diff"] = (df['Diff'] - df['Diff'].shift())

print(df)
            value   Diff
Date                    
2015-05-04      1    NaT
2015-05-06      1 2 days
2015-05-07      1 1 days
2015-05-11      1 4 days
2015-05-11      1 0 days
```

Comment: That does it. Actually, I also realised that i needed to format the dates from strings before applying the above (i.e. replace the first line with df["Diff"]=pd.to_datetime(df.index,dayfirst=True))