# how to calculate the (pandas) timedeltas between TimesStamps in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe with a TimeStamp column. I want to add another column with the timedeltas from one cell to the next. Which is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: did you try `df['TimeStamp'].diff()`?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices

Comment: @Andy, the problem asked in your link adds another layer: groupby. .diff() will work just find for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> df['TimeStamp'].diff()

Answered by [@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum)