# Find number of gaps per hour in 10 second interval data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My data is organized in 10-second intervals for 24 hours:

```
2015-10-14 15:01:10 3956.58 0   19  6.21    105.99  42  59.24  
2015-10-14 15:01:20 3956.58 0   1   0.81    121.57  42  59.24  
2015-10-14 15:01:30 3956.58 0   47  8.29    115.53  42  59.24  
2015-10-14 15:01:40 3956.58 0   79  12.19   107.64  42  59.24 
..   
..   
..     
2015-10-15 13:01:10     3956.58 0   79  8.02    107.64  42  59.24   
2015-10-15 13:01:10     3956.58 0   79  7.95    108.98  42  59.24
2015-10-15 13:01:10     3956.58 0   79  7.07    110.58  42  59.24
```

I want to check if, for any hourly group, there are intervals that exceed 10 seconds. How do I get the gaps for each group and print it? So far I've the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('convertcsv.csv', parse_dates = True, index_col=0,
                 names=['date', 'hole_depth', 'rop', 'rotary',
                        'torque', 'hook_load', 'azimuth', 'inclin'])
df['num_gaps'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)
df.groupby(df.index.time)['num_gaps'].sum()
```

I want the output to be:

```
timestamp, num_of_gaps  
2015-10-15 06:00, 5  
2015-10-15 07:00, 0   
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a great answer to get you started.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices) Your case is different as you would like to first group by hour and then look for differences larger than 10 seconds (avoids the date difference problem mentioned in the answer).

So you could try, assuming your `DataFrame` comes with `DateTimeIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd
df['tvalue'] = df.index
time_groups = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H'))
for hour, data in time_groups:
    data['delta'] = (data['tvalue']-data['tvalue'].shift()).fillna(0)
    data['delta_sec'] = data['delta'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(10,'s'))
    print(data[data.delta_sec > 10])
```

Just saw your edit - you could of course also just count the values per hour and check if the `.count()` is lower than the 360 one would expect. In other words,

```
print(df.groupby(TimeGrouper('H')).size())
```