# Time difference between indices with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compute the difference between consecutive data row's timestamps.

**Why does this work**, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices) :

```
df['tvalue'] = df.index
print df['tvalue'].shift() - df['tvalue']
```

but not

```
print df.index.shift() - df.index
```

which produces `ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq` ?

*The problem is that the working solution doubles the memory size needed for timestamp; this is a problem for huge dataframes.*

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just input a frequency, either `shift(1)` or `shift(-1)`

```
print df.index.shift(1) - df.index

print df.index.shift(-1) - df.index
```