# how to get time difference in minutes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  code     start_time      end_time
  0        13:00:09        13:30:09
  1        14:23:33        15:23:23
  2        11:30:00        12:30:00
```

`start_time` and `end_time` are of type objects.

I want to get difference of these two columns in minutes. I am doing following in pandas

```
df['time_diff'] = pd.Timestamp(df['start_time']) - pd.Timestamp(df['end_time'])
```

Comment: Not end time substract with start time ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices should be of help to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) or to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), convert output timedeltas to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide `60`:

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'].astype(str)) 
end_time = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'].astype(str))

#another solution
#start_time = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'].astype(str)) 
#end_time = pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time'].astype(str))

df['time_diff'] = start_time.sub(end_time).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print (df)
   code start_time  end_time  time_diff
0     0   13:00:09  13:30:09 -30.000000
1     1   14:23:33  15:23:23 -59.833333
2     2   11:30:00  12:30:00 -60.000000
```

If swap end time with start time:

```
df['time_diff'] = end_time.sub(start_time).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print (df)
   code start_time  end_time  time_diff
0     0   13:00:09  13:30:09  30.000000
1     1   14:23:33  15:23:23  59.833333
2     2   11:30:00  12:30:00  60.000000
```

**Sample**:

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [0, 1, 2], 
                  'start_time': [datetime.time(13, 0, 9), datetime.time(14, 23, 33), 
                                 datetime.time(11, 30)], 
                   'end_time': [datetime.time(13, 30, 9), datetime.time(15, 23, 23),
                                datetime.time(12, 30)]})

print (df)
   code start_time  end_time
0     0   13:00:09  13:30:09
1     1   14:23:33  15:23:23
2     2   11:30:00  12:30:00
```

IDE from comment, thanks @Anton vBR:

```
start_time = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
end_time = pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()

df['time_diff'] = end_time.sub(start_time).div(60)
print (df)
   code start_time  end_time  time_diff
0     0   13:00:09  13:30:09  30.000000
1     1   14:23:33  15:23:23  59.833333
2     2   11:30:00  12:30:00  60.000000
```

Comment: it gives me following error `<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

Comment: @Neil - then is necessary convert it to strings by `.astype(str)`

Comment: Oops, thought they were both the same thing you had accidentally pasted twice. Sorry

Comment: @coldspeed - No problem.

Comment: @Neil - Give me a sec for sample

Comment: @Neil - added data sample, for me it working nice. Can you check it?

Comment: Tbh, when I see timestamps I prefer converting it to seconds and skip the whole datetime thing altogether.

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thanks, added to answer how I understand your comment ;)

Comment: @jezrael I had first converted to time with following `data['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_time'],format = "%H%M%S").dt.time`

Comment: @Neil - yes, need remove `dt.time`, then it working nice alos without converting by `.astype(str)`