# Using Python to deduce delta between consecutive timestamps

Tags: python, plot, graph, average

I have a data set (fairly large) parsed from a log file that looks like the following:

`{ id_1: [(1, 1554251220), (2, 1554252310), (3, 1554253199),...], id_2: [(1, 1554251220), (2, 1554252310), (3, 1554253199),...], id_3: [(1, 1554251220), (2, 1554252310), (3, 1554253199),...] ... }`

It is a dictionary with each key having a list of tuples as its value. The keys represent unique ids, while the first element of the tuples represents a version number and the second, a timestamp.

I want to be able to find the time difference between each subsequent version for each of the ids i.e. the time difference between version 1 and 2 and then version 2 and 3 and then 3 and 4...

Like:

```
    timestamp(2) - timestamp(1) = 1554252310 - 1554251220
    timestamp(3) - timestamp(2) = 1554253199 - 1554252310
    ...
```

```
    for key in dictionary:
         for i in range(len(dictionary[key])):
               delta = dictionary[key][i][1] - dictionary[key][i+1][1]
               outlist.append(delta)
```

I have tried parsing out each list, for each id and calculating the time deltas but it has not worked. Would the best way to achieve this involve `pandas`? Like here: [Calculate time difference between Pandas Dataframe indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices)

Is there any way I could do so, without using `pandas`?

Once I have these - what is the most efficient way to go about determining average deltas across all ids?

Comment: please post what you have tried, and explain the problem(s) with it.

Comment: Done, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Are you sure that all deltas > 0 ? and tuples are sorted by version number? You may need to apply sorting first  (to guarantee deltas > 0).

Comment: Tuples are all sorted by version number..

Comment: "... and explain the problem(s) with it."  Something a bit deeper than "it has not worked".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
deltas = {}
for id, stamps in dictionary.items():
     if id not in deltas:
         deltas[id] = [] 
     for i in range(len(stamps) - 1):
         deltas[id].append(stamps[i+1][1] - stamps[i][1])
print(deltas)
```

And to get the average of deltas you can use `statistics.mean()`:

```
from statistics import mean
for id, delta in deltas.items():
    print(id, mean(delta))
```

Comment: Running into cant convert tuple to numerator/denominator error for the means() call

Comment: Can you post a real sample of the dataset so we can test the code on it? It is preferable that you post a sample with the data that is causing the error.