# pandas select rows with given timestamp interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe of the form

```
timestamp | col1 | col2 ...
```

I want to select rows spaced out by an interval of at least x minutes, where x can be 5,10,30, etc. The problem is the timestamps arent equally spaced, so I cant do a simple "take every nth row" trick.

Example:

```
timestamp | col1 | col2

'2019-01-15 17:52:29.955000', x, b
'2019-01-15 17:58:29.531000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:21:48.255000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:27:46.324000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:33:09.984000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:22:08.170000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:28:27.406000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:34:35.194000', x, b
```

if interval = 10:

result:

```
'2019-01-15 17:52:29.955000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:21:48.255000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:33:09.984000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:22:08.170000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:34:35.194000', x, b
```

if interval = 30:

result:

```
'2019-01-15 17:52:29.955000', x, b
'2019-01-16 03:21:48.255000', x, b
'2019-01-16 07:22:08.170000', x, b
```

I could do a brute force n^2 approach, but I'm sure theres a pandas way for this that im missing..

Thank you! :)

EDIT: It is not a duplicate of [Calculate time difference between Pandas Dataframe indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices) just to clarify. I need to subset a dataframe based on a given interval

Comment: I think a loop is necessary here. Dropping one row then impacts the decision of all other rows, for instance if you had rows `1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 20, 27` you don't know to keep 12 until you've dropped 2 3 and 4 for being too close to 1 (if the diff is >10).

Comment: @ALollz Not really, if you instead generated an index of rows to keep, you could subset them immediately, no?

Comment: @steven how is this a duplicate? Its asking a completely different thing. Please do not flag unnecessarily.

Comment: looks like you need to make do with a simple `for` loop. It's `O(n)`, not `O(n**2)`.

Comment: you just need to calculate the difference between rows and then select between on it right?

Comment: @steven None of the answers there are applicable. That question is asking for the time difference between successive rows, if you read my post the rows are not successive, and its not just about the time diff between the nth and n+1th row, I need a minimum of x difference between rows (which can be cumulative)

Comment: ok, pls add those details to the post. Thx

Comment: @steven If you had read both posts the differences would have been clear.

Comment: I did, which is why I flagged. Could you post a non-pandas way code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like commented, it looks like you need to do a `for` loop. And it is not too bad because you are doing an `O(n)` loop:

```
def sampling(df, thresh):
    thresh = pd.to_timedelta(thresh)
    time_diff = df.timestamp.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
    ret = [0]
    running_total = pd.to_timedelta(0)
    for i in df.index:
        running_total += time_diff[i]
        if running_total >= thresh:
            ret.append(i)
            running_total = pd.to_timedelta(0)

    return df.loc[ret].copy()
```

Then `sampling(df, '10T')` gives

```
                timestamp col1 col2
0 2019-01-15 17:52:29.955    x    b
2 2019-01-16 03:21:48.255    x    b
4 2019-01-16 03:33:09.984    x    b
5 2019-01-16 07:22:08.170    x    b
7 2019-01-16 07:34:35.194    x    b
```

and `sampling(df, '30T')` gives:

```
                timestamp col1 col2
0 2019-01-15 17:52:29.955    x    b
2 2019-01-16 03:21:48.255    x    b
5 2019-01-16 07:22:08.170    x    b
```

Comment: Thank you! :) '10T' gave me an error but '10M' worked fine, thanks alot!

Comment: Hm.. Was looking for a non-for-loop solution. But looks good.