# how to fix chaining df.index.to_series().diff()

Tags: python, pandas

I've read SO questions and watched videos about SettingWithCopyError and I know it happens when there is chain of methods, when pandas is not sure whether you want to change original or create a copy.

I have datetime index, I am calculating time differences between each row thanks to [Calculate time difference between Pandas Dataframe indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices)

```
avg_gps = df.loc[ (df["serial_number"] == "AA6NF4") ]
avg_gps["time_diff"] = avg_gps.index.to_series().diff()
```

However on the second line of code it gives me SettingWithCopyError which I know it is because I am chanining. However I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: `df.loc[(df["serial_number"] == "AA6NF4"),"time_diff"] = avg_gps.index.to_series().diff()`

Comment: `avg_gps.assign(time_diff = avg_gps.index.to_series().diff())`

Comment: Thanks guys! didn't know about df.assign. Thanks

Comment: @QuantStats I do not have avg_gps df yet. to use your methods first I need to copy df into avg_gps which output same warning