# Python pandas date difference between rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, date-difference

I've got a pandas dataframe 'A' with a column 'date' containing timestamps in the following format:

> 2020-06-09 13:30:11.359497

I need to calculate the time difference between every line and the previous in minutes.
I've tried Timedelta, shift and diff.

Comment: Did you first convert the dates from type 'string' to type 'datetime'? Then, using timedelta should help.

Comment: Please include [`minimal reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

import time

t1 = '09/06/2020 13:30:11.359497'

t2 = '10/06/2020 09:30:12.352452'

# convert t1, t2 to type datetime

date_time_t1 = datetime.strptime(t1, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

date_time_t2 = datetime.strptime(t2, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# convert date_time_t1, date_time_t2 to Unix timestamp
timestamp_1 = time.mktime(date_time_t1.timetuple())

timestamp_2 = time.mktime(date_time_t2.timetuple())

# the difference in minutes
print(int(timestamp_2 - timestamp_1) / 60)
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a col. for eg. 'next': will store next day's time and 'diff': difference between the timestamps

```py
df['next']=df['A'].shift(periods =1 ,  fill_value=0)
df['diff']=df['A']-df['next']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also do this in one line (well actually two also counting the copying)

```
df["diff"] = df.Dates
df["diff"] = df.Dates.shift(periods=-1)- df.Dates
```

Answer (score 1):

using pandas functions:

```
df['next'] = df.Col1.shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0)
df['diff'] = (df.next - df.Col1)/np.timedelta64(1,'m') # converting to minutes, np is numpy module
```

using user defined function (can have more control and u can make changes as per ur need):

```
def find_diff(date_list):
    dif_list = []
    for x, y in zip(date_list, date_list[1:]):
        dif_list.append((y-x).total_seconds()/60)
     return pd.Series(dif_list)

df['diff'] = find_diff(list(df.Col1))
```