# How to subtract Time objects within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df and would like to subtract two time values within a column:

[image: Pandas DataFrame Picture]

For Example: 04:01:00 - 04:00:00 = 00:01:00
df.Time[i+1] - df.Time[i]

Does anybody have an idea, how I can fix this using a for loop? Have some difficulties using the for loop as well as dealing with the datatype.

Thanks!

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780413/2681435

Comment: Don't use a loop: `df['Time Difference'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DataTime']).diff()`

Comment: Thank you so much MOZWAY, it worked! :-)