# Difference in time between successive dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, python-datetime

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777570/calculate-time-difference-between-pandas-dataframe-indices) question, I would like to compute the time difference between rows of a dataframe. Unlike that question however, the difference should be by `groupby` id.

So foe example, this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': [6,6,6,6,6,10,10,10,10,10],
 'timestamp': ['2016-04-01 00:04:00','2016-04-01 00:04:20','2016-04-01 00:04:30',
              '2016-04-01 00:04:35','2016-04-01 00:04:54','2016-04-30 13:04:59',
              '2016-04-30 13:05:00','2016-04-30 13:05:12','2016-04-30 13:05:20',
               '2016-04-30 13:05:51']}
)
df.head()
    id        timestamp
0    6  2016-04-01 00:04:00
1    6  2016-04-01 00:04:20
2    6  2016-04-01 00:04:30
3    6  2016-04-01 00:04:35
4    6  2016-04-01 00:04:54
5   10  2016-04-30 13:04:59
6   10  2016-04-30 13:05:00
7   10  2016-04-30 13:05:12
8   10  2016-04-30 13:05:20
9   10  2016-04-30 13:05:51
```

Then I want to create a column `ΔT` for the differences, like so:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['ΔT'] = df.groupby('id').index.to_series().diff().astype('timedelta64[s]')

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Intended output:

```
    id        timestamp        ΔT
0    6  2016-04-01 00:04:00    0
1    6  2016-04-01 00:04:20   20
2    6  2016-04-01 00:04:30   10
3    6  2016-04-01 00:04:35    5
4    6  2016-04-01 00:04:54   19
5   10  2016-04-30 13:04:59    0
6   10  2016-04-30 13:05:00    1
7   10  2016-04-30 13:05:12   12
8   10  2016-04-30 13:05:20    8
9   10  2016-04-30 13:05:51   31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df["ΔT"] = df.groupby("id").diff()
df["ΔT"] = df["ΔT"].dt.seconds
df["ΔT"] = df["ΔT"].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id           timestamp  ΔT
0   6 2016-04-01 00:04:00   0
1   6 2016-04-01 00:04:20  20
2   6 2016-04-01 00:04:30  10
3   6 2016-04-01 00:04:35   5
4   6 2016-04-01 00:04:54  19
5  10 2016-04-30 13:04:59   0
6  10 2016-04-30 13:05:00   1
7  10 2016-04-30 13:05:12  12
8  10 2016-04-30 13:05:20   8
9  10 2016-04-30 13:05:51  31
```